# undefined values being copied to the options input

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to creating a list of options from the already existing array. Here is the code:

```
const channelOptions = res.data.data.deliverables.map((item, index) => {
          if (!item.deliverableCosts.length)
            return (
              <option value={item.slug} key={index} channel={item.channel.slug}>
                {item.name + '(' + item.channel.name + ')'}
              </option>
            );
        });
```

Now if the condition does not match, it gives me an undefined value.
Could someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the undefined values?

```
const channelOptions = res.data.data.deliverables.map((item, index) => {
      if (!item.deliverableCosts.length)
        return (
          <option value={item.slug} key={index} channel={item.channel.slug}>
            {item.name + '(' + item.channel.name + ')'}
          </option>
        );
 }).filter(i => i);
```

Or use reduce instead:

```
const channelOptions = res.data.data.deliverables.reduce((carry, item) => {
      if (!item.deliverableCosts.length)
        carry.push(
          <option value={item.slug} key={index} channel={item.channel.slug}>
            {item.name + '(' + item.channel.name + ')'}
          </option>
        );
      return carry;
 }, []);
```